# Fechar tooltip no Full Calendar

Tags: jquery, css

Estou tentando fechar minha tooltip no calendario jQuery:

[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/oorb5wnk/)

Clicando no evento, irá aparecer a tooltip e um " x " no canto superior, ao clicar nele a tooltip deve ser fechada, o codigo no JS na linha 16 chama a funcao para fechar.

Porém não estou tendo resultados.

**JS**

```
$.fn.popover.defaults.container = 'body';

$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar({
             header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
                    element.popover({
                        title: 'My Title <div id="x-fechar">x</div>',
                        placement:'top',
                        html:true,
                        content: event.msg
                    });
                    $('#x-fechar').click(function(e){
                        element.popover('hide');
                    });
                  },
                 editable: false,        
          events: [
                    {
                        title  : 'Click me 1',
                        msg: 'I am clipped to the left which is annoying',
                        start  : '2014-09-01 06:00:00',
                        end  : '2014-09-01 08:00:00',
                        editable: false,                            
                        allDay : false
                    },
                    {
                        title  : 'Click me 2',
                        msg: 'I am OK',                            
                        start  : '2014-09-04 14:00:00',
                        end  : '2014-09-04 15:00:00',
                        editable: false,                                                        
                        allDay : false 
                    }               
                ]
        });
```

Comment: Furlan, é importante [incluir seu código na pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1913/posso-mostrar-s%C3%B3-um-link-pro-meu-site-com-problemas).

Comment: Dica2: o botão `TidyUp` lá no jsfiddle é tipo tudo de bom :)

Comment: cara...q btn lindo!! *-* kkk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o `#x-fechar` [ainda não existe no DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122150/jquery-selecting-elements-that-dont-yet-exist), tem que declarar seu `click()` assim:

```
$(document).on("click", "#x-fechar", function(e){ 
    element.popover('hide');
});
```

Mas como é mais de um elemento, deve-se usar uma classe `.x-fechar`. Não achei um jeito oficial de fazer isto, mas para saber qual popover pertence a qual evento, podemos adicionar o ID do evento no elemento `.x-fechar`:

```
title: 'My Title <div class="x-fechar" data-eid="'+event._id+'">x</div>',
```

E conferir durante o clique:

```
$(document).on("click", ".x-fechar", function (e) {
    if( $(this).data('eid') == event._id )
        element.popover('hide');
});
```

```js
$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2014-09-01',
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        element.popover({
            title: event.title + '<div class="x-fechar" data-eid="'+event._id+'">x</div>',
            placement: 'top',
            html: true,
            content: event.msg
        });
        $(document).on("click", ".x-fechar", function (e) {
            if( $(this).data('eid') == event._id )
                element.popover('hide');
        });
    },
    editable: false,
    events: [{
        title: 'Evento 1',
        msg: 'Lorem ipsum lorem.',
        start: '2014-09-01 06:00:00',
        end: '2014-09-01 08:00:00',
        editable: false,
        allDay: false
    }, {
        title: 'Evento 2',
        msg: 'Ut enim ad minim veniam',
        start: '2014-09-04 14:00:00',
        end: '2014-09-04 15:00:00',
        editable: false,
        allDay: false
    }]
});
```

```css
#mycalendar {
    margin:30px;
    height:600px;
    max-width:500px;
}
.x-fechar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0px 20px 0 0px;
    margin: -15px 0 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="mycalendar"></div>
```

Tem um bug quando mudamos a visualização no calendário (p.ex., trocar de mês) que faz com os popovers não sumam e não possam ser fechados pelo botão `.x-fechar`.

Para consertar isso acrescentei o evento `viewDestroy` que é disparado a cada troca de visualização:

```
viewDestroy: function( ev, el ) {
    $('.popover').each(function(){
        $(this).remove();
     });
}
```

Comment: entendi...eu ja imaginava que era isso, so nao sabia como resolver, tenho alguns projetos que faço partes com AJAX, e nao funcionava por causa disso, ele nao tava no DOM, mto obrigado @brasofilo vai ser mto util!

Comment: esta funcionado, mas por exemplo, eu tenho 2 tooltip aberta, quando eu clico em fechar, ela fecha as 2 nao a que eu escolhi

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com um jeito de detectar isso.

Comment: boaa ! valew @brasofilo.... obg mesmo

Comment: @Furlan, tava fuçando no calendar e descobri um bug, atualizei a resposta.

Comment: @brasofilo, reparou que quando aumenta ou diminui a área no jsfiddle o tooltip se sobrepõe?

Comment: @PapaCharlie, fora do fiddle vejo que ele não se movimenta, no fiddle meio que tenta acompanhar a célula de origem.

Comment: @brasofilo Imaginei que fosse dentro do fiddle mesmo. Deve conflito quando redimensiona o frame.

Comment: @PapaCharlie, é, tem alguma coisa estranha, o último código que postei não roda lá...

Comment: @brasofilo, Quando ha sobreposição o [X] não fecha o anterior, só o ultimo... Acho que é o plugin mesmo que colide com a área.